# How can i achieve segmented control view in MAUI

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

[image]

i want to achieve this kind of view please help in new to MAUI

I don't want to use trial nuget package syncfusion, telerik etc

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gpproton/181a9263721be1dc6625ae44e1eccc19

Comment: I would have your VIewModel contains 3 ObservableCollections: (1) Your complete list, (2) Your 3 segments, (3) Your filtered list. The first collection is non visible. The second collection drives your segment choice. The third collection drives your content. You can use LINQ to populate the third collection via a getter based on the choice from your second collection and your underlying data. OnPropertyChanged() will drive the connections between the 2nd and 3rd collections.